# Sharing visual studio with remote developer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am looking for a software/plugin to allow two users share working session in vs.net 2010 w/o using SVN or similar software. Is there anything (commercial or free)?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/overview

Comment: Sorry, wasn't descriptive enough. Something like this: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/collabvs/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

the product [VSAnywhere](https://vsanywhere.com/) works great and likely does exactly what you want!

Comment: Sadly, VSAnywhere now gone.

Comment: @solvingJ have you tried ScreenHero, which is now part of Slack?

Comment: No, I had not seen that yet.  While it seems more like a screen sharing tool and less like the real-time IDE-Integrated pair programming plugin I wanted, the videos show independent mice and keyboards which might actually work.  Who knows, it might even be better in some cases.  Gonna have to test it.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do pair programming on this one session?  If so try using some implementation of VNC to share the screen and Skype for communication.

Comment: Skype can also be used to share the screen/current window. So you get voice/video and screen sharing all in one place.

Comment: Allon, can you take control of the pc using a shared skype screen or is it strictly view only?

Comment: Nope. It seems you can only share your screen, not your keyboard and mouse. There are plugins for Skype that will allow you to collaborate, but ymmv greatly with those.